# Build a Custom Curl Request within Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hi I am trying to run a curl from with in java springboot 
`curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/containers/json`

I have created a service class

```
public Long getContainerPort() {
        logger.info("Calling  Container Api");
        Long containerPortNumber = defaultContainerPortNumber;
        List<ContainerPort> containerPorts = Arrays.asList(restTemplate1.getForObject(curlURIBuilder.toUriString(), ContainerPort[].class));
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(containerPorts)) {
            logger.debug("Container Api response is empty. So returning defualt port");
            return containerPortNumber;
        }
        for (ContainerPort containerPort : containerPorts) {
            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(containerPort.getPorts())) {
                continue;
            }
            for (Port port : containerPort.getPorts()) {
                if (port.getPrivatePort() == 8081) {
                    containerPortNumber = (null == port.getPublicPort() ? containerPortNumber : port.getPublicPort());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        logger.debug("Container port is: {}", containerPortNumber);
        return containerPortNumber;
    }

}
```

This is working for just sending a simple curl request i.e `curl  http://localhost/containers/json`

without `--unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock`

I used UriComponentbuilder to build `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/containers/json`
but get an error 
`uri is absolute`

Comment: That's... not a URI.

Comment: whats the best way to achieve this